# Syntax highlighting mode for SLIME in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, slime

How do I enable the syntax highlighting mode for SLIME in emacs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get syntax highlighting for common lisp in SLIME's REPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809493/how-can-i-get-syntax-highlighting-for-common-lisp-in-slimes-repl)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that by SLIME you mean the SLIME REPL. It uses **repl** major mode and you cannot just enable font-locking for it, since there is one enabled already and it's simply different from that in **lisp-mode** and **clojure-mode** for instance. Your best bet might be to play around with the font-lock faces for **repl-mode**. [This article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/jYShTPC_ppk) might prove helpful.